# Blazor - "Aw, Snap! Error code: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION" error if breakpoint is set

Tags: blazor, breakpoints, blazor-server-side, visual-studio-2022, razor-component-library

I have a Blazor server-side app, which uses my component library as a project reference.

If I set a breakpoint in code of a component from the library and run in debug mode, my app start page is shortly shown then Aw Snap! error occurs.

If I run app and then set or enable the breakpoint, everything works correctly.

What can cause the error? How to rid of it?

Debug in VS 2022 with IIS, Google Chrome 96.0.4664.45 x64

Comment: Does this happen with other browsers?

Comment: In Microsoft Edge it happens too. Error code: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Comment: How about non-chrome browsers like FF?

Comment: I've tried and there is no the error in FireFox!

Comment: It might be related to a bug in chrome. If you google the error code, you will get entries dating from 2020 related to this bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occures when the option 'Javascript-Debugging for ASP.NET' is activated.
I got rid of the problem by deactivating this option in VS.